# Script to read user commands from a file for c++ program

Tags: bash

I am new to scripting. Facing a problem in trying to do the following. Please help.

My C++ program runs in a while loop, receives commands from the user on a prompt, and executes them. I want to automate this process.

Sample execution

```
$ ./my_tool

my_prompt> command1 arg1 arg2

result: abc

my_prompt> command2 arg3

result: xyz

my_prompt> command3 abc xyz

result: my_result

my_prompt> exit

$
```

Now, I want to have a file, input.txt, which will have

```
command1 arg1 arg2
command2 arg3
command3 <abc> <xyz>
exit
```

Execution of the script will be something like

```
./run ./my_tool input.txt
```

How do I write a simple bash script to achieve this? I will have at least 20 commands.

If I don't have command3, that is, all input parameters are predetermined, then how can I proceed?

Sorry if this is really simple - I am not able to figure out.

Thanks and regards,
SB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the file line by line to the binary as stdin:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    eval $1 < $line
done <<< "$2"
```

Quick explanation:
The IFS thing will make sure the file will be read line by line, otherwise it would create a new iteration on each whitespace. The line `./my_tool < $line` will pass `$line` as `stdin` to your program so the stdin buffer (where you would read user input from) is filled with the data, so your program reads the "input". `done < "$2"` will pass the first argument as file to the while loops input, where `read` will read the input. `$2` will be the filename you pass the script upon execution. `eval $1` will run the command that is stored in `$1` which is your first parameter of the script.

To use it run:

```
chmod +x myscript.sh # you need to do this only once
./myscript.sh ./my_tool input.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting `$line: ambiguous redirect` for each line of the input file and `exit: No such file or directory` on the last line for `exit`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Changing the last line to `done <<< "$2"` is working for me. Is that a proper thing to do here?

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed.